# JPanel not being paint in JFrame

Tags: image, graphics, jpanel, repaint, paintcomponent

I'm fairly new to java and decided to make a 2D game. I am trying paint the panel but it simply doesn't work. I have done the same type of thing with JFrames and it worked, but if possible I would like to get it to work with JPanels. Here is some code

This is in a class used only for drawing the map. Images are called from an enumeration

```
   //called in paint method for panel
public void draw(Graphics2D g2){
    sLevel1.setupRect();
    for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++){
        for(int e = 0; i < 24; i++){
            if(level1.worldDat[i][e] != 0){
                int c = level1.worldDat[i][e];
                if(i == 1){
                    g2.drawImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(eBlocks.GRASS1.getPath()), e*20, i*20, null);
                }else if(i == 2){
                    g2.drawImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(eBlocks.GRASS2.getPath()), e*20, i*20, null);
                }else if(i == 3){
                    g2.drawImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(eBlocks.GRASS3.getPath()), e*20, i*20, null);
                }else if(i == 5){
                    g2.drawImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(eBlocks.BORDER.getPath()), e*20, i*20, null);
                }else{
                    g2.drawImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(eBlocks.NULL.getPath()), e*20, i*20, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is where its called in the panel,

```
    @Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){     
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    super.paintComponent(g2);
    worldDraw.draw(g2);
}
```

and Finally this is where it is added in the JFrame and the timer is used to repaint

```
    public mainGameFrame() {
    super("Tile Game");
    setResizable(false);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 510, 525);

    //i also tried add, didnt work either
    setContentPane(gamePanel);

    addKeyListener(this);

    Timer time = new Timer(32, new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            repaint();
            gamePanel.repaint();
        }
    });

    time.start();
}
```

Comment: I had a similar question like you, but no one answered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do and why it's not working (have you tried to step through it with a debugger? What did you discover?), but here is my recommendation based on the information you did supply.

Get rid of the `draw()` method for now (just comment it out if you like). Instead, do this in the `paint()` method:

```
public void paint( Graphics g ) {
    super.paint( g );

    // draw something simple here, just so you know it's getting called, like a filled Rect
    g.setColor( Color.BLUE );
    g.fillRect( 0, 0, 50, 50 );

    // try drawing the image later, after you verify this is being called with your rect
//    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
//    g2.drawImage( Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(eBlocks.GRASS1.getPath()), e*20, i*20, null);
}
```

If your filled rect works, but your image doesn't, you know there's something wrong with your images, and you can go down the path of fixing that.

There's really not much information here, but there isn't much info in your question either. I can give a better response if I know precisely what's wrong. "It simply doesn't work" isn't a lot to go on.